# Class Type Error

Tags: c++

I am working on a project where I input a string, and it outputs that string on separate lines of the console. I have got that to work, but my question/error is when I am looking for a specific position of that word. An error message pops up regarding the "unsigned searcher = str.find("good");" with a red underline under "str" saying it needs a class identifier. I have looked online for examples but have no been able to solve this. Please help!

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
char str[] = "   Hello good sirtttttt..!.";
char * pointer_char;
int pos = 0;
std::string str;
int i = 0;
int length = strlen(str);




string good; // word/char that i want to search

    cin >> good;

for (i = 0; i < length; i++) //i<string size
{
   unsigned searcher = str.find("good");
   if (searcher != string::npos) {
       cout << "found at : " << searcher;
   }
```

}

Comment: When asking a question regarding compiler or linker errors, then you should include the actual errors in the question (unedited and complete). You might want to read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 4):

```
char str[] = "   Hello good sirtttttt..!.";
...
std::string str;
```

You have two variables with the same name. Name one differently.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple declaration of str.

```
char str[] = "   Hello good sirtttttt..!.";
char * pointer_char;
int pos = 0;
std::string str;
```

There is no need to use a char array. Change it to:

```
//char str[] = "   Hello good sirtttttt..!.";
char * pointer_char;
int pos = 0;
std::string str = "   Hello good sirtttttt..!." ;
int length = str.size();
```